# How do I install a .deb file silently and automatically?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, installation, silent-install

OS: Debian 11

My goal is to install a .deb file silently and automatically from a bash script.

The command I am running inside a bash script is

```
sudo apt install -y ./*.deb
```

I get this screen

[image]

Yes, I can hit "Enter" on my keyboard, I can use the mouse to hit "OK" too.
I don't want to.

**What command do I run to auto-select "OK" when prompted so that everything is automatic?**

Comment: Which specific .deb file? The answer depends entirely on what is being done by the .deb file's pre/post scripts.

Comment: Honestly, no idea. I need to do an offline install of ZFS on Debian 11. I downloaded all packages necessary. here is a complete list.

libnvpair3linux_2.0.3-9_amd64.deb  python3-distutils_3.9.2-1_all.deb
libuutil3linux_2.0.3-9_amd64.deb   zfs-dkms_2.0.3-9_all.deb
libzfs4linux_2.0.3-9_amd64.deb     zfsutils-linux_2.0.3-9_amd64.deb
libzpool4linux_2.0.3-9_amd64.deb   zfs-zed_2.0.3-9_amd64.deb
 
When I install run sudo apt install -y ./*.deb      They install and everything works, but its not silent. I need it silent and I need to skip that screen that asks for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The message is shown via debconf, by [the `config` script](https://salsa.debian.org/zfsonlinux-team/zfs/-/blob/master/debian/zfs-dkms.config) of the "zfs-dkms" package.

It's technically implemented not as a *message* but a debconf *input* dialog which gets a specific parameter, so you can avoid it by manually adding the parameter into debconf's database before installation:

```
echo zfs-dkms zfs-dkms/note-incompatible-licenses note true | debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: I tried your command and got

debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

After searching the internet, I stumbled upon an answer that works:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ./*.deb
```